# Duplicate partitioned table into another partitioned table taking all partitions in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to duplicate a partitioned table into another partitioned table, taking all the partitions and the schema.

I've found this command on the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#bq_2):

```
bq cp \

'mydataset.mytable$20180130,mydataset.mytable$20180131' \

myotherproject:mydataset.mytable2
```

That allows me to copy multiple partitions at the same time, but forcing me to write all the partitions references by hand.
Is there a way to automate the process and take all the existing partitions?